# Form Fails to Requery After Query SQL Altered (MS Access 2003/VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have an MS Access 2003 form based on a select query. It contains several combo boxes that can be used to filter the form records. All but one of them work as expected and the only way I can get that one to work is by replacing part of the query's SQL using VBA:

```
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery")
qdfOLD = qdf.sql
qdf.sql = Replace(qdf.sql, strOldCriteria, strNewCriteria)
Me.Requery    ' I've also tried DoCmd.Requery and Forms!MyForm.Requery
qdf.sql = qdfOLD
Set qdf = Nothing
```

The replacement part works fine and if I leave out the last three lines, then view the query in Datasheet view, I will see only the expected records. But for some reason the form is not requerying - i.e., I still see all the records, not the filtered sub-set. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how to do it.

You either change or modify the `RecordSource` of the form using and SQL expression, or apply a filter string to the `Filter` property of the form.

Whenever you do this, the form will requery.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, though. I made the other combos on the form work using the Filter property, but that didn't work in this case. I guess I could create another query and modify the RecordSource, as you said. But I'd still like to know why this approach doesn't work in this case. I'm using it successfully on this same form (with a button click) to modify a query and then requery another open form. Why can't I requery the current form?

Comment: I guess the query is cached. You could try just setting `Me.RecordSource = Me.RecordSource` to make the from requery. But again, this is not how to do it, or - if you like - it is a suboptimal method.